# VUE firebase Making UI elements contingent on logged in state? Works when logged in, throws error when logging out

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs3

Hi I am trying to have a logged in state that has elements that are based on which user is logged in.

I get the user from firebase auth and then use the uid to check firestore for their data. This all works on the login however when I logout it throws the below error.

```
export default {
  setup() {
    const { user } = getUser();
        if (user) {
          const { error, document } = getDocument("collection", user.value.uid);
          console.log(document);
          return { document };
        }}}
```

HTML

```
 {{ document.gender }}
```

Error Received:

> Profile.vue?49d8:13 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'uid' of null
> at setup (Profile.vue?49d8:13)
> at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154)
> at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6542)
> at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6503)
> at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4206)
> at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4182)
> at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3791)
> at componentEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4298)
> at reactiveEffect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:42)
> at effect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:17)

**getUser function**

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { projectAuth } from '../firebase/config'

// refs
const user = ref(projectAuth.currentUser)

// auth changes
projectAuth.onAuthStateChanged(_user => {
  console.log('User state change. Current user is:', _user)
  user.value = _user
});

const getUser = () => {
  return { user } 
}

export default getUser
```

**Get Document function**

```
    import { watchEffect, ref } from 'vue'
    import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'
    
    const getDocument = (collection, id) => {
    
      let document = ref(null)

  let error = ref(null)

  // register the firestore collection reference
  let documentRef = projectFirestore.collection(collection).doc(id)

  const unsub = documentRef.onSnapshot(doc => {
    // need to make sure the doc exists & has data
    if(doc.data()) {
      document.value = {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
      error.value = null
    }
    else {
      error.value = 'that document does not exist'
    }
  }, err => {
    console.log(err.message)
    error.value = 'problem fetching the document'
  })

  watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
    onInvalidate(() => unsub())
  });

  return { error, document }

}

export default getDocument
```

Comment: You should share the code of the `getUser()` function. We cannot know what is user.value with only the code in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that I have added the getUser and getDocument functions thanks!! @RenaudTarnec